# particle animation too slow

Tags: iphone, particles

I'm trying to draw several particles as we touch and moving. When user tilts the device, particles moves to the tilted side.
I made this steps by using each particles on each Image View. But it's too slow when making like 100 image views.

```
SoilView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentPoint.x + randomDist1, CurrentPoint.y + randomDist2, 30, 30)];

[SoilView setImage:SoilImage];
```

so I tried to change this to particle animation, but it was not working well. most particle animation sample was just blowing up or scatters everywhere. so I couldn't find a way to make my code.
Is there any ways to make each particles to work like each views?
How can I solve this problem? Could Someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would use OpenGL for particle animations. To get you started take a look at this [particle Generator](http://code.google.com/p/iphoneparticles/) and the OpenGL ES Blog posts of the project's author http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html